# Why is PSModulePath not a PowerShell variable

Tags: powershell, console

I keep looking at this, and I cannot for the life of me understand why `PSModulePath` is an environment variable. Is there *any* rational reason for this?

To explain further, `$profile` is a PowerShell variable. You can invoke it simply by typing `$profile`. This makes sense. However, `PSModulePath` has absolutely no relevance or function outside of PowerShell, and yet, for some unintelligble decision, it has been set as an environment variable. i.e. it cannot be viewed by `$PSModulePath`, and can only be viewed by doing `echo $env:PSModulePath`. Making it even more irrational is that there is a `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` which again is a PowerShell variable and not an Environment variable ...

The `PSModulePath` variable is 100% only for PowerShell. Can anyone explain a rationale for this extremely odd setup?

Comment: PSMODULEPATH is read by the PowerShell executable before the PowerShell session is established, and thus must be available in the environment. It's not intended to be a "user variable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$env:PSModulePath` is required before the Powershell session is loaded. I believe (and I could be wrong on the "why" here) this is because several "built-in" cmdlets are defined within modules themselves, and need to be loaded on startup. Notably, you'll see this if you look at a specific module directory defined in `$env:PSModulePath`, which is the System module path:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

Generally you don't want to install your modules here and should remain "clean", as in, let MS manage the modules in this directory.

Comment: ok, thanks, that sounds like it must be the reason. It's a shame though as it looks quite odd. I guess that means that PowerShell will be forever shackled to DOS in this way; would be nice to think that DOS could be retired at some point in future but I guess this means that it will always have to be there like some vestigial appendage....

Comment: It's not really shackled to DOS, environment variables are part of the operating system. Variables defined outside of Powershell Core on Linux are referenced the same ways, using the `Env:` provider or the `$env:` variable.

Comment: I guess so, that's reasonable enough. It's still a *bit* odd for the reasons that I mention - because by that argument, $Profile could then just as easily be considered a part of the operating system also, or indeed, we could say that PowerShell is "a part of the operating system" and then $PSModulePath and $Profile would be the same type of variable, but thanks for the rationale on that.